# Speed up PowerShell script ( Invoke-Sqlcmd and Word Object )

Tags: powershell, t-sql

So i have this loop in my script:

```
foreach ( $candID in Get-Content $candList )
{
    $candID = $candID -replace '\s',''
    $candID

    $templateDir = Get-ChildItem ($ScriptPath + "Templates\Resumes\") | Get-Random -Count 1 
    $templateFile = $templateDir
    $templateDir =  ($ScriptPath + "Templates\Resumes\" + $templateDir)

    $lname = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT LEFT(personFirstName, 1) FROM tblPErson WHERE personID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName

    $firstname = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT personFirstName FROM tblPErson WHERE personID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName
    $surname   = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT personSurname FROM tblPErson WHERE personID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName
    $Address1  = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT CandidateAddress FROM tblCandidate WHERE CandidateID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName
    $City      = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT CandidateCity FROM tblCandidate WHERE CandidateID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName
    $Postcode  = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT CandidatePostcode FROM tblCandidate WHERE CandidateID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName
    $Mobile    = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT personMobileTelephone FROM tblPErson WHERE personID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName
    $State     = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT CandidateState FROM tblCandidate WHERE CandidateID = $candID" -serverinstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName

    $firstname = $firstname.ItemArray[0]
    $surname   = $surname.ItemArray[0]
    $Address1  = $Address1.ItemArray[0]
    $City      = $City.ItemArray[0]
    $Postcode  = $Postcode.ItemArray[0]
    $Mobile    = $Mobile.ItemArray[0]
    $State     = $State.ItemArray[0]
    $lName     = $lName.ItemArray[0]

    cls

    ### Loop Visual
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Generating resumes" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Write-Host " ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Using resume template: $templateFile" -foregroundColor GREEN
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Data:"

    Write-Host "    Firstname   = $firstname"
    Write-Host "    surname     = $surname"  
    Write-Host "    Address1    = $Address1" 
    Write-Host "    City        = $City"     
    Write-Host "    Postcode    = $Postcode" 
    Write-Host "    Mobile      = $Mobile"   
    Write-Host "    State       = $State"    

    ### End Loop Visual

    $filename = ($firstname + " " + $surname + " - " + $candID + ".doc")
    $filename2 = ($firstname + " " + $surname + " - " + $candID + ".txt")

    $saveAs = ($scriptPath + "Documents\Original Resumes\" + $lName + "\" + $filename)
    $saveAs2 = ($scriptPath + "Documents\Original Resumes\" + $lName + "\" + $filename2)

    $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application
    $doc=$objWord.documents.Add($templateDir)  
    $objWord.Visible = $false 
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("Address1").Range.Text = $Address1 
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("firstName").Range.Text = $firstname
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("surName").Range.Text = $surname
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("City").Range.Text = $City
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("Postcode").Range.Text = $Postcode
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("Mobile").Range.Text = $Mobile
    $doc.Bookmarks.Item("State").Range.Text = $State
    $doc.SaveAs([REF]$saveAs)
    $doc.Close()

    $doc2=$objWord.documents.Add($saveAs) 
    $doc2.SaveAs([REF]$saveAs2, [REF] 2)

    $objWord.Quit()
}
```

Basically, I am creating spoof resumes for records in the database using word templates. The script works but it is only creating around 2 - 3 resumes every 5 seconds, this is a bit of an issue since I need to fill the entire database ( 1 million spoofed records ).

Plus, it will only get longer since at some point I will be customising this so the template isn't random but instead catered to the industry of the person, as well as adding a lot more data into each resume ( skills, references etc ).

Is there anything I can do to speed this up a bit?

Comment: 1st thing would be to reduce your SQL to one statement. You dont need to query for each value in a single query. Bring it into one. Should only have to make the one `$objWord`. Initialize it once _outside_  the loop. Quit outside as well. If you can avoid it dont waste time writing information to console. It is slow. If you want logging put it in a file.

Comment: Ok, thanks! and in doing that each value would be a different number in the item array? so surname would be sqlResult.ItemArray[1] ?

Comment: Made all those changes, it is now 7 - 8 per 5 seconds, which is a decent increase, thanks. will still take 8 days ish to make all the resumes, but its better than 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is ensuring that you are running this script under PowerShell 3.0 or higher. The office COM objects are known for poor performance in PowerShell 2.0, and without editing your script it will likely run faster.

For your script as a whole, I would adjust the portion of retrieving data from SQL Server. As commented you can make this into one call.

Which without having sample data or knowing what that file in `$candList` really contains, you can make the top half of your script something like this:

```
$candData = Get-Content $candList -Raw | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace '\s',''}

$qry = "
    SELECT personFistName,
        LEFT(personFirstName, 1) AS personLastName,
        personSurname,
        CandidateAddress,
        CandidateCity,
        CandidatePostcode,
        personMobileTelephone,
        CandidateState
    FROM tblCandidate
    WHERE personID IN ($($candData -split ','));
"
$templateDir = Get-ChildItem ($ScriptPath + "Templates\Resumes\") | Get-Random -Count 1 
$templateFile = $templateDir
$templateDir =  ($ScriptPath + "Templates\Resumes\" + $templateDir)

$data = Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance $ServerAddress -Database $DatabaseName -Query $qry

foreach ($row in $data) {
    $lname = $row.personLastName
    $firstname = $row.personFirstName
    $surname   = $row.personSurname
    $Address1  = $row.CandidateAddress
    $City      = $row.CandidateCity
    $Postcode  = $row.CandidatePostcode
    $Mobile    = $row.personMobileTelephone
    $State     = $row.CandidateState
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this, sorry, I'm relatively new to PowerShell. Is this just storing every row in the database in an object? Wouldnt that cause some issues with 1000000 rows being stored in $data?

Comment: Just tried this and it didn't work, the candList file is just a list of ID's separated by newlines. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException: Incorrect syntax near '1330002'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '1330002'.